# Flutter Wrap widget rendering glitches when height is updated

Tags: flutter, visual-glitch

I am creating a form (not using the `Form` Widget) in Flutter where the user can add an arbitrary amount of items (treatments) which are rendered as `InputChip` widgets list in a `Wrap` widget.

The form uses a button (`AddButton` widget) which opens a form dialog which itself returns the newly created item (treatment) that is added to *selectedItems*:

```dart
class TreatmentsWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const TreatmentsWidget({super.key, required this.selectedItems});

  final List<Treatment> selectedItems;

  @override
  State<TreatmentsWidget> createState() => _TreatmentsWidgetState();
}

class _TreatmentsWidgetState extends State<TreatmentsWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var chips = widget.selectedItems.map(
      (item) {
        return InputChip(
          label: Text('${item.name} - ${item.frequency}/${item.frequencyUnit.name})',
        );
      },
    ).toList();

    return Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Wrap(
          children: chips,
        ),
        AddButton(onPressed: () {
          showDialog(
              context: context,
              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                return const TreatmentDialog();
              }).then((value) {
            if (value != null) {
              Treatment item = value;
              setState(() {
                widget.selectedItems.add(item);
              });
            }
          });
        }),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason, when a new item is added to *selectedItem* and that the item overflows the current line, the layout is not recomputed such that the `Wrap` widget overflows the button:

[image: 2 chips]

[image: 3 chips glitch]

However, as soon as the user scroll (the whole screen content is inside a `SingleChildScrollView`), the layout is recomputed and the `Wrap` takes the right amount of space:

[image: 3 chips]

How can I force a redraw when a new item is added to prevent this glitch?

Comment: if you are new to flutter the best way to manipulate the state of the app as you want is this: https://pub.dev/packages/provider, https://docs.flutter.dev/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple, You can achieve these redraws through provider, and much more as to make your application faster

Comment: Also for now try to wrap your Column with SingleChildScrollView. It may work

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be that the `Column` does not recompute its size on the current frame when one of his child size changes.

I ended up forcing rebuilding the `Column` using a `ValueKey` whenever `chips.length` changes:

```dart
class _TreatmentsWidgetState extends State<TreatmentsWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var chips = ...;

    return Column(
      key: ValueKey(chips.length),
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Wrap(
          children: chips,
        ),
        AddButton(...),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

I am still interested in a cleaner solution if it exists. Using a provider seems overkill for this case.